# mysql select record in where clause using substring

Tags: mysql, select, substring, where-clause

I have the five records which is like below. I need to fetch the data which have 'rock'. So I need the output like this, the output should display the count of 'rock', so according to the above database the output count should be "3" i.e., rec 1, rec 3 & rec 5". So the count should not take "rec 2 & rec 4".

```
rec1: [u'armenian rock', u' armenian', u' singer-songwriter', u' rock'] 
rec2: [u'punk', u' armenian rock', u' new wave', u' italian'] 
rec3: [u'rock']
rec4: [u'japanese', u' okuda tamio related', u" rock'n'roll", u' roots rock'] 
rec5: [u'test rock', u' armenian', u' singer-songwriter', u" rock"]
```

Comment: Show us what you have done so far to select the required data.

Comment: what did you tried your self...

Comment: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table1 WHERE INSTR(Table1.tags, '\' rock') > 0;

Comment: tired these also where INSTR(ma.tags, '\' rock\'')>0

Comment: if i understand correctly, you want to display the all rock field or otherwise?

Comment: rec1,rec2,rec3, etc., mean field or table pls,,

Comment: field name "tags", the field contains that values [u'armenian rock', u' armenian', u' singer-songwriter', u' rock'].

Comment: example, in my hand just have rock(consider as PHP variable), now I need to fetch the data which have 'rock'. i.e., rec 1, rec 3 & rec 5 not take "rec 2 & rec 4